# Intellij IDEA problems auto complete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea

I have a problem when I code with Intellij IDEA and I write for example "path" and I put the "=" automatically it puts me that "{}" just after the equal. Is there any way to disable this?

[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDFlR.png)

I have searched in the settings of Intellij IDEA but I did not find anything

Comment: did you search for auto-completion in settings?

Comment: Set "Add for JSX attributes" to None in Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML > Other.